# How to call a webservice from GPS device

Tags: c#, web-services, proxy, gps

I have a GPS device from GPS Tracker company. The thing is that i don't want to use their server & instead i want to create one of my own. So what i did up-till now is that i have created a WebService which i want to call from my GPS device. Now the GPS device only have IP address & Port in its config file.

After thorough research i found out that i need to create proxy services which the GPS device will call which in turn will call the WebService.

My question is that how to create this proxy service & once created what address shall i provide to IP Address & Port in GPS config File.

Please Help Me. Thanks a tonne in Advance.

Comment: Just run the tracker in your lan, sniff the packet and reverse engineer the protocol. You wouldn't have to do it if the company provide a public API though.

Afterwards you implement the protocol in your web service. The address and port obviously depend on where you deploy the web service

Comment: How do i run it and sniff package

Comment: I know for sure the GPS device uses TCP/IP Protocol. I just want to create a proxy that listens to TCP/IP requests.

Comment: [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) if it happen to be purely http, you'll go wild with proxy if it use https. Honestly though, it's better that you start attempting to sniff it and ask specific question about the problem in your steps

Comment: After much research i found out that i need to create a wcf service with TCP bindings (endpoints). But i could not understand till yet that i will define multiple methods in wcf service so how will the gps device know which method to call.

Comment: That's the 'reverse engineer the protocol' part. You need to let your device run normally and communicate with the vendor's server, capture whatever they're sending & receiving. From there you can deduce how to create the the method etc.

Comment: But how will i catch GPS packets being sent from the GPS device. Because it uses a SIM card with GPRS to send packets.

Comment: Create an open proxy that will just forward whatever it received to the original IP and port, then change the IP & port in your device to your proxy IP & port. Sniff the packets from the proxy

Comment: By using your idea i was just able to fetch the packets thanx a lot man, +1 for your advice. Sorry to ask again but the data in the packet is somewhat encrypted, i mean i cant get the NMEA string. Could you guide me something about that.

Comment: Ouch, that's probably impossible if they implement asymmetric encryption. However it's more likely they are just encoded somehow (Base64 or whatever serialization). You can try post the packet you sniffed here. By the way, what is the vendor? It seems odd that you don't mention looking up the vendor's documentation?

Comment: Its Xexun TK-102 GPS Tracker

Comment: Follow the instructions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12298302/api-dev-specs-or-similar-for-tk102-gps-localizer). From what I see they are actually simple CSV messages.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88153/discussion-between-martheen-and-murtaza-munshi).